# Issues in printing out php array

Tags: php, arrays

Unfortunately **I am struggling to print some array items in PHP** and was hoping someone could assist me. Slightly embarassing :) I think I might be using arrays incorrectly? I am trying to build an application object from the database and once this has been done i am trying to iterate over it and print some basic details. I have also included the separate Application class.

```
<?php

include("application.php");

$applicationsForUser = array();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username=$_POST["username"];
    $password=$_POST["password"];
    $userid = logUserIn($username, $password);
    if($userid > 0){
        getAppInformation($userid);
        foreach ($applicationsForUser as $app) {
            echo $app->$getUserid() . $app->$getName();
        }
    }
}

function getAppInformation($userid){
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost:3306', 'root', '', 'clientportal');
    if ($conn->connect_errno > 0) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }else{
        //we have connected to the database
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM application WHERE userid = '$userid'";
        if(!$val = $conn->query($sql)){
            die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
        }else{
            $index = 0;
            while($row = $val->fetch_assoc()){
                $userid = $row['userid'];
                $name = $row['name'];
                $dateCreated = $row['date'];
                $invoice = $row['invoiceid'];
                $comment = $row['commentsid'];              
                $application = new Application($userid, $name, $dateCreated, $invoice, $comment);
                $applicationsForUser[$index] = $application;
                $index++;
            }
        }
    }
    $conn -> close();   
}




<?php
class Application {

    var $userid;
    var $name;
    var $dateCreated;
    var $invoice;
    var $comment;

    function Application($userid, $name, $dateCreated, $invoice, $comment) {
        $this ->userid = $userid;
        $this ->name = $name;
        $this ->dateCreated = $dateCreated;
        $this ->invoice = $invoice;
        $this ->comment = $comment;
    }

    function getUserid(){
        return $this ->userid;
    }

    function getName(){
        return $this ->name;
    }

    function getDateCreatd(){
        return $this ->dateCreated;
    }

    function getInvoice(){
        return $this ->invoice;
    }

    function getComment(){
        return $this ->comment;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. In which part of your code you are facing problem?

Comment: you could assume from the title that the problem lies in the area where i am printing the array content out :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that $applicationsForUser is supposed to be global. Therefore you need to use

```
function getAppInformation($userid){
    global $applicationsForUser;
```

Otherwise your foreach iterates over an empty array here:

```
    getAppInformation($userid);
    foreach ($applicationsForUser as $app) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use globals:

You didn't initialize your array before trying to loop through it.

```
<?php

include("application.php");


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username=$_POST["username"];
    $password=$_POST["password"];
    $userid = logUserIn($username, $password);
    if($userid > 0){
        // get application information
        $applicationsForUser = getAppInformation($userid);
        foreach ($applicationsForUser as $app) {
            echo $app->$getUserid() . $app->$getName();
        }
    }
}

function getAppInformation($userid){
    $applicationsForUser = array();
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost:3306', 'root', '', 'clientportal');
    if ($conn->connect_errno > 0) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }else{
        //we have connected to the database
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM application WHERE userid = '$userid'";
        if(!$val = $conn->query($sql)){
            die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
        }else{
            $index = 0;
            while($row = $val->fetch_assoc()){
                $userid = $row['userid'];
                $name = $row['name'];
                $dateCreated = $row['date'];
                $invoice = $row['invoiceid'];
                $comment = $row['commentsid'];              
                $application = new Application($userid, $name, $dateCreated, $invoice, $comment);
                $applicationsForUser[$index] = $application;
                $index++;
            }
        }
    }
    $conn -> close();
    return $applicationsForUser; 
}
```